# SQL Server Indexing

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing, internals

I am trying to understand what is going on with `CREATE INDEX` internally. When I create a `NONCLUSTERED` index it shows as an `INSERT` in the execution plan as well as when I get the query test.

```
DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses s
WHERE spid = 73 --73 is the process creating the index
SELECT TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
GO
```

Show:

```
insert [dbo].[tbl] select * from [dbo].[tbl] option (maxdop 1)
```

This is consistent in the execution plan. Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my lack of knowledge on indexes, what a difference 4 months of experience makes! :)

The index creation will cause writes to the index to insert the leafs as needed.